# Add class & style to Raphaël JS Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, raphael

I have made a map using the Raphaël JS plugin. I would like to add classes to my elements (paths of different countries) in order to add CSS to the countries (to colour them). Could anyone help me please ?
Here is the fiddle I have made : https://jsfiddle.net/2e0bqmd3/
Thanks in advance for your answers,
Kindest regards.

```
#canvas_eu_central_east {
width: 692px;
height: 700px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KarlRichter I have read your links, but I don't know what's wrong with my question

Comment: 90%+ of you code is country coordinates which isn't very minimal. Reduce them e.g. to two fictional square countries. If the coordinates are all important explain, why this is the case.

Comment: @KarlRichter ok thx now I understand. All countries are important because it is a map and I just would like to add different colours to these countries because I want to show a legend with CSS. I have reduced the number of countries. [https://jsfiddle.net/2e0bqmd3/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/2e0bqmd3/1/)